# Ticking/tapping sound

Tags: sounds

Recently I have had a ticking/tapping sound that seems to happen every 48-52 seconds. It always comes in threes and has completely moved from one end of my house to the other.

It almost sounds like a device that is ticking or tapping.. I know its not my ducting, I shut power and water off to my house and the noise still occurred.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: 48 to 52 sec is very specific.  Can you tell us more? Is it continuous?

Comment: Is it seasonal?

Comment: Its continous through the day basically nonstop...it did stop for 4 hours after moving to the new location.. as for seasonal I couldn't tell you just bought the house this summer and its our first seasonal change.. it started Saturday the day I fired up the furnace (coincidentally?) that night it started. Regardless I truly do no believe its HVAC related just due to the sound its definitely not sheet metal clanging.

Comment: Impossible to say without a lot more detail. That said, if the sounds moves around, there's a good chance it's an animal, e.g. mouse. It could be nibbling or scratching at things, looking for a way past an obstruction, getting nesting material, whatever. If you have a video, you can upload to YouTube, Vimeo, whatever, and just provide a link here.

Comment: "*it started Saturday the day I fired up the furnace (coincidentally?)*" Probably not. Tell us more about what kind of heating system you have. Have you shut the furnace off for a while to see if the sound continues?

Comment: HVAC sounds don't usually involve "clanging". They're ticking when the metal expands and slips along wood against which it rests.

Comment: If you have a gas furnace,  the igniters might be periodically re-lighting if something in the electronics is messed up.  this would explain the very repeatable pattern timing.  If  you have a heat pump,  there is a "defrost" circuit which can chatter, and again a fault would be required for it to trigger over and over again.  As to it sounding like it had moved, unless vents are being closed I cant explain this.

Comment: With a repeat interval of less than one minute it should be very easy to better locate the source. Simply reposition around the house listening for when it is louder or softer etc, stand near the furnace, outside, whatever it takes to understand where it it strongest.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. Luckily for me the sound has stopped and never did figure out what it is or was. I spend the better part or 8 hours searching for it short of ripping down walls. Listened to vents. Turned power and water off to house multiple times. It sounds alot simpler to figure out over the message board but I've done everything recommended 5 times over. All I hope is it's gone for good

Answer (score 1):

There is an insect called a deathwatch beetle. It makes a ticking / tapping sound to attract a mate. [Follow this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathwatch_beetle) to the Wikipedia page that includes a recording of the sound.